# advanced custom fields: repeater field within conditional statement

Tags: php, conditional-tags, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to have a custom field within a conditional statement.
e.g—

```
if ( is_page( 'about' ) || '29' == $post->post_parent ) {
                //custom field goes here
                }

elseif ( is_page( 'contact' ) || '30' == $post->post_parent ) {
                //custom field goes here
                }
```

and the custom field to go within:

```
<?php while(has_sub_field('site_slideshows','option')): ?> 

<div class="slideshow-slide" style="background-image:url(<?php the_sub_field('site_slideshows_slide_image'); ?>)">
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Is it at all possible to put a custom field within a conditional tag? Each custom field will be different obviously, that's just an example of what i want to go `custom field goes here`. 
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see why that shouldn't work. Have you tried it? Does it not work for you, what happens?

Comment: @jzatt well replacing the `custom field goes here` with the custom field code I've given above brings up a syntax error, unexpected `>` etc etc. I'm not sure if I have to change the format of it, I'm not overly familiar with conditional tags? Any suggestions as to how that could be written?

Comment: @jzatt well replacing the custom field goes here with the custom field code I've given above brings up a syntax error, unexpected > etc etc. I'm not sure if I have to change the format of it, I'm not overly familiar with conditional tags? Any suggestions as to how that could be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pasted the exact second block you'll get errors because you are breaking up the closing and opening PHP tags `<?php` and `?>`. Try this instead, or have a look at this for a better understanding, notice the difference ...

```
if ( is_page( 'about' ) || '29' == $post->post_parent ) {
    //Start of the custom code...
    while(has_sub_field('site_slideshows','option')):
    ?> <!-- Closing the PHP tag -->

        <div class="slideshow-slide" style="background-image:url(<?php the_sub_field('site_slideshows_slide_image'); ?>)">
        </div>

    <?php //Opening the PHP tag again
    endwhile;

} elseif ( is_page( 'contact' ) || '30' == $post->post_parent ) {
    //Start of the custom code...
    while(has_sub_field('site_slideshows','option')):
    ?> <!-- Closing the PHP tag -->

        <div class="slideshow-slide" style="background-image:url(<?php the_sub_field('site_slideshows_slide_image'); ?>)">
        </div>

    <?php //Opening the PHP tag again
    endwhile;
}
```